# scrolling horizontally through divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to make it possible to align divs with a lot of text horizontally, so you can scroll through them horizontally. Not really experienced and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong..

Here is my css:

```
#content {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 70%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  overflow: scroll;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please make a demo on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to put multiple `.item`s into the `#content` and they should then wrap horizontally. Is that correct?

You would then need a wrapper over your `#content` that has a fixed width (this is going to be your 'scroll window'). The `#content` itself needs to be wider so that you can scroll it while the wrapper needs the property `overflow-x:scroll`. Since you don't know how wide your `#content` should be (except if you know the number of `.item` divs) I  suggest to set it with Javascript. Finally it's important to have `float: left` in your `.item`, otherwise they won't wrap horizontally.

Additionally you could let JS set your `#content`s height to the heighest `.item` if you don't want this to be same for all `.item`s.

Take a look [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nD33/1/) if this is what you try to achieve.

Optionally you could use css3 columns. However you wouldn't yet use it, as you won't have any support for IE9 and below. [See here how this works.](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-use-css3-columns/)

Cheers!